# MySQL "CREATE USER" on PythonAnywhere

Tags: mysql, pythonanywhere

I'm connecting with my MySQL database using my user and host listed in Databases tab. No problems with that.

But I want to create a new user for that database (the user that I will use to my app connect with the database), but when I tried `CREATE USER` statement, I got a permission error:

`ERROR 1227 (42000): Access denied; you need (at least one of) the CREATE USER privilege(s) for this operation.`

What I can do to accomplish that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: pythonanywhere mysql user has no permission for create user. you don't make user

Comment: We don't provide CREATE USER permissions on PythonAnywhere. The user that we create for you is the one that you have.